# For loop and next method to iterate the generator, it is OK that fulfill my expectation

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, generator

I test the performence of these method:

```
def gen_iter():
    for _ in xrange(100000):
        yield _

def for_perf():
    it = gen_iter()
    for _ in it:
        pass

def next_perf():
    it = gen_iter()
    try:
        while True:
           _ = it.next()
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

These are the test result(for_next_perf is the module name):

```
python -m timeit "from for_next_perf import for_perf; for_perf()"
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 msec per loop

python -m timeit "from for_next_perf import next_perf; next_perf()"
10 loops, best of 3: 39 msec per loop
```

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
 7    8.527 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
 8                             def for_perf():
 9    8.531 MiB    0.004 MiB       it = gen_iter()
10    8.582 MiB    0.051 MiB       for _ in it:
11    8.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           pass
```

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
13    8.508 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
14                             def next_perf():
15    8.512 MiB    0.004 MiB       it = gen_iter()
16    8.562 MiB    0.051 MiB       while True:
17    8.562 MiB    0.000 MiB           try:
18    8.562 MiB    0.000 MiB               _ = it.next()
19    8.562 MiB    0.000 MiB               pass
20    8.551 MiB   -0.012 MiB           except StopIteration:
21    8.551 MiB    0.000 MiB               break
```

Sorry, I made a mistake previous that forget to loop for that generator. Now it fulfill my expectation.
However, I found the memory usage was increasing at runing time that use the style of `for_perf()` in my work. Huh, may be is my fault, I should go to test my code carefully again.

Comment: `_ = it.next()` gets you the first value from the generator and after that the function returns. Of course it'll be faster than getting *all*  values from generator.

Comment: yeah you gotta bring the `while` inside the `try`

Answer (score 0):

As per @vaultah's comment, you're comparing two different operations.  You're consuming the generator fully in the first code snippet, while only getting the first element out of the generator object in the second.

```
def next_perf():
    it = gen_iter()
    while True:
        try:
            _ = it.next()
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopIteration
            # In working code you will break rather than re-raise.  Not sure how the time changes if you re-raise, I assumed it won't change too much (loop terminates either way), but that's a big assumption.
```

This is what the second code should look like if it were to do the equivalent operation to the first, and will almost certainly take longer than the other version.

btw, it's really bad practice to `yield _`.  Only use `_` for throw-away values that you literally do nothing with.

Comment: You want the `while` loop **inside** the `try` or use `break` to end the loop when a `StopIteration` is caught. Either way, you don't want to raise the exception *again*.